# Compare lab tests in 2 sas datasets

Tags: sql, sas, trial

I have 2 lab datasets (A and B) in SAS. Dataset A has all the tests that need to be done for every visit. Structure for this dataset is like visit (screening, Day-1, Day 1....)and each visit has fixed tests done per protocol.
Dataset B is where actual data resides containing patient ids, visit and tests.
The question is how to use sas code to find which tests from Dataset A are not done in Dataset B for each subject and each visit.
Thanks so much for all the help.

Comment: Can you post example datasets and explain what you've tried to do?

Comment: `Select * FROM A LEFT JOIN B on A.ID = B.ID WHERE B.ID is null`  left join says include all records from A and only those in B that match.  Since you want the ones in B that didn't match an A value just show the ones where B.ID is null.  (Assuming you have a key value/Values between the datasets  [SAS Docs on Joins](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002473691.htm)